# Show pulsing cursor but do not open the keyboard when textfield is initialized

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I don't want the keyboard to automatically appear when I'm pressing on the widget. However, I want to show the cursor to indicate that there's a textfield in this area. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of one workaround for this. You can add *FocusNode* to your field and listen to changes. When the field get focus, hide the keyboard.

```dart
  final FocusNode fn = FocusNode();
  fn.addListener(() {
    // You can control here whether or not you want to hide automatically shown keyboard
    if (fn.hasFocus) {
      // Hiding the keyboard 
      SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
    }
  });

  ...
  // Pass the focus node to text field:
  TextField(
    focusNode: fn
  );
```

I haven't tested it, though.